# Can Anyone help me with this code, i'm trying to clear a textbox when bs is pressed(Jquery)?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

The problem is that I want to clear the txt_monto when a user press Backspace, I already tried:

`if(e.keyCode == 8){
                          $("#txt_monto").val(accounting.formatMoney(0, '$'));
                     }`

But it only works on Opera, on Firefox, IE or Chrome it doesn't work.

```
if(e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57)
              {
           if($("#txt_monto").val().length > 1)
                   {    
                            var current_value = parseFloat($("#txt_monto").val().replace('$',''));
                            // e.preventDefault();
                            //Key code is always going to be higher than 48..
                            var value = parseFloat(e.keyCode) - 48;
                            value = (current_value * 10) + value;
                            $("#txt_monto").val(accounting.formatMoney(value, '$'));
                        }
              }
          else
              {
                  if(e.keyCode == 8){
                      $("#txt_monto").val(accounting.formatMoney(0, '$'));
                  }
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
```

This is the whole script, everything looks correct to me, I have tried and I don't think it's a syntax problem I think there is something else wrong, something about Chrome and IE, because it works fine on Opera:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#txt_monto").keyup(function(){

                       var value = $('#txt_monto').val();
                          $(this).val(accounting.formatMoney(value, '$')); 


        });
         $("#txt_monto").keypress(function(e){

           if(e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57)
              {
                    if($('#txt_monto').val().length > 1)
                        {

                            var current_value = parseFloat($("#txt_monto").val().replace('$',''));
                            // e.preventDefault();
                            //Key code is always going to be higher than 48..
                            var value = parseFloat(e.keyCode) - 48;
                            value = (current_value * 10) + value;
                            $("#txt_monto").val(accounting.formatMoney(value, '$'));
                        }
              }
          else
              {
                  if(e.keyCode == 8){
                      $("#txt_monto").val(accounting.formatMoney(0, '$'));
                  }
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
        });


      });
```

OK, This is my HTML For that part:

```
   <td> <p> Monto a regargar: </p>   </td>

   <td><input type="text" class="txt1" name="txt_monto"  id="txt_monto" maxlength="4" ></td>
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? Might be helpfull.

Comment: Thanks Wesley, but the problem is no that "'", that was a typo when I was typing the question.

Comment: It would be excellent if you can provide also your HTML.

Comment: My HTML is there now..

Comment: I tried var = e.Which || e.keyCode; and that didn't work and tried
""var key = myEvent.keyCode ? myEvent.keyCode : myEvent.which ? myEvent.which : myEvent.charCode;""
and that didn't work either

Comment: I found the answer... thanks for the help though..

Comment: @Molinator You can answer your own question here and share it us.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like the following script to properly assign the keycode to a variable, then use that variable as the keycode (not e.keycode). I'd give you more information but I am still learning javascript myself.

```
$(document).keypress(function (myEvent) {
    var key = myEvent.keyCode ? myEvent.keyCode : myEvent.which ? myEvent.which : myEvent.charCode;
});
```

Like I said, I'm still learning it myself, but I use this code all the time for functions similar to the one you have there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you try this?

```
$("#txt_monto").keypress(function(e){
           var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
           if(key >= 48 && key <= 57)
              {
                    if($('#txt_monto').val().length > 1)
                        {

                            var current_value = parseFloat($("#txt_monto").val().replace('$',''));
                            // e.preventDefault();
                            //Key code is always going to be higher than 48..
                            var value = parseFloat(key) - 48;
                            value = (current_value * 10) + value;
                            $("#txt_monto").val(accounting.formatMoney(value, '$'));
                        }
              }
          else
              {
                  if(key == 8){
                      $("#txt_monto").val(accounting.formatMoney(0, '$'));
                  }
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
        });
```